# Order of elements in a set in java

Tags: java, set

If i create 2 lists from the same set, can I be sure that I get the same ordering in both the lists? (I do not care about the ordering as long as both the lists have the same order and I am not performing any operations on the sets between creating the two lists.)

```
List l = new ArrayList(set);

List l1 = new ArrayList(set);
```

I understand that there are guaranteed ways of creating these lists and getting the same order and that there isn't a good reason for me to create two lists this way, but I would like to know why the ordering of elements in a set would change if no modify operations are performed on it.

Edit: The set is an unordered HashSet

Comment: If it's a hashset, no if it is mutated inbetween (ordering is not guaranteed, but it won't change without the set being modified). If it's anything else, the ordering would be defined so you can adjust based on that.

Comment: This is completely implementation dependent. I can conceive of an implementation where iterating through the set would somehow change the order of the set. Very unlikely, but possible, and there is no guarantee it won't happen.

Comment: No. A `Set` provides **no guarantees** as to its iteration order. Not even that it is consistent. It may choose to use your access as an excuse to tidy up the internal structure thereby changing the order on next iteration.

Comment: @Boris, this isn't a property of `Set` per se. For example, some sets like `TreeSet` and `LinkedHashSet` guarantee the iteration order.

Comment: @aetheria it absolutely is: from the [JavaDoc for `Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator()) - "_The elements are returned in no particular order_". I.e. `Set` specifically states that it provides no guarantees. Talking about specific implantations is completely irrelevant - much like saying that a `Set` can be stored in a database because `PersistentSet` happens to be.

Comment: I agree 100% that you should not rely on an iteration order if you are given an arbitrary `Set`. What I meant (pedantically) was that some implementations of `Set` *do* guarantee iteration order. They are still Sets, i.e. there *are* Sets that do guarantee iteration order. The distinguishing property of a Set is that it contains no duplicates. All implementations must comply with this constraint. But implementations are free to offer guarantees about iteration order or persistence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will *propably* get the same ordering in the lists `l` and `l1`. But since most Sets are unordered, you have no *guarantee* that there will be the same order.

Technically you could write an implementation of the `Set` interface which changes its order everytime any method is called. This would still fulfil the interface.

Since in the constructor `new ArrayList(Collection)` the `toArray` method of the collection is called, we can have a look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of `Set#toArray()`:

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this set. If this set makes any guarantees as to what order its elements are returned by its iterator, this method must return the elements in the same order.

While the Javadoc of `Set#iterator()` says there is no general guarantee:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set. The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).

Given this, I would strongly advise you **not to rely on the ordering of the lists.**

Answer (score 4):

As per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection))

> public ArrayList(Collection c) Constructs a list
>   containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they
>   are returned by the collection's iterator

So it really depends on the `Set` interface implementation class, if the order is constant.

For example, if you use `LinkedHashSet` the iteration order is predictable.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no set implementation currently provided by the major implementations for which this is not true, but it does not mean that there can't be one.

Comment: In my case, I'm using the unordered hashset.

Comment: For the HashSet `public Iterator<E> iterator()`
returns an iterator over the elements in this set. The elements are returned in no particular order. It looks you can not rely on this order.

Answer (score 0):

There are structures that their orders are guaranteed or not. If we mention of `Set` interface implemented by Java, there is no guarantee. Most likely the constructor of `ArrayList` make uses of iterator of `Set`. So both list certainly contain always same elements but order. That's actually why `Set` uses `contains` keyword instead of `find` to check an element whether it exists.

> It's sub-interface, [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), represents a set that is sorted
>   according to some criterion. In Java 6, there are two standard
>   containers that implement `SortedSet`. They are [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and
>   [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html).
>
> In addition to the `SortedSet` interface, there is also the
>   [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) class. It remembers the order in which the
>   elements were inserted into the set, and returns its elements in that
>   order.

Answer (score 0):

One way to impose a desired (natural, or otherwise) order on an unordered collection like a `Set` is to create an ordered `Set` (in other words, a `SortedSet`) from the given set. If your sets are not too large and all you care for is a predictable iteration order, you can do:

```
// set = ...
List<? extends Comparable> list = new TreeSet<>(set).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This assumes that the set consists of elements that are comparable. Alternatively, you could use your own comparator in the `TreeSet` constructor. There may be some issues in creating such a comparator however, if the elements themselves are not comparable.

Answer (score -3):

There are some intertesting and good answers here, I can propose a solution.

```
List list = new ArrayList(set);

List secondList = new ArrayList(list);
```